# Cant update instance variables after getting data from api call

Tags: swift, amazon-dynamodb

This is the instance variable in my class
     var restaurants = String;

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)
    if (self.user == nil) {
        self.user = self.pool?.currentUser()
    }
    self.title = self.user?.username
    // fills the list with a certain data set 
    //self.refresh()
```

This is my completion block

```
    grabData {
        for values in self.restaurants{
            print(values)
        }
    }


}
```

This is the function making the api call

```
func grabData(completion : @escaping() -> ()){

    let databaseMap = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
    let expression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()


    databaseMap.scan(Restaraunt.self, expression: expression,completionHandler:{(response:AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?,error:Error?)-> Void in

        // testing the response
        if(response != nil){
            print("got a reponse")
            if(response?.items.count == 0)
            {
                print("did not get a response")
            }else{


                for item in (response?.items)!{

                    let data: Restaraunt = item as! Restaraunt;

                    let name: String = data._name as! String;
                    self.restaurants.append(name)
                }

            }                
       }
   })

   completion()
}
```

The function doesn't seem to update the instance variable, I know that I am getting the proper data back after I setup some break points. (When I set a break point on the for loop it shows the restaurants instance variable to be empty).

Comment: You have to call `completion()` inside the completion handler of  the `scan` method, not after it.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `completion()` incorrectly. It is called before you actually get your data. You have to call it from the completion handler:

```
databaseMap.scan(Restaraunt.self, expression: expression, completionHandler: { (response: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: Error?) in

    // testing the response
    if (response != nil){
        print("got a reponse")

        if (response?.items.count == 0) {
            print("did not get a response")
        } else {
            for item in (response?.items)! {
                let data: Restaraunt = item as! Restaraunt;
                let name: String = data._name as! String;
                self.restaurants.append(name)
            }
        }                
    }

    // this has to be inside the closure
    completion()
})
```